# Open text file located at desktop

Tags: permissions, text

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and I have a text document file at my desktop. When I double click it, this error is displayed:

[image: error when double-clicking file on desktop]

So I tried unchecking *Allow executing file as a program*.

[image: file properties window]

This solved my issue, but I noticed that this setting is applied to all text documents on my laptop.

How can I save this setting for this specific text file only?

Comment: I can launch TXT files on Desktop without error even if "allow executing…" is checked. Go to [Activities](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-introduction.html.en#activities), search "Extensions" and tell us what GNOME extension you’re using + details (Desktop Icons ? Version ?) + click on "Website" and share the URL if possible.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "save this setting for this specific text file" ?

Comment: I right clicked this file and unchecked the option from properties. So when I go to properties of an another text file then its *Allow executing file as a program* is also unchecked. I meant to say that I don't want to apply this setting to every text document ,I want to apply this setting only for a text document that I want. @zatiranyk

Comment: You've already done what you want. The other text files *already* had that setting, as is usual.